# Reset the element to initial html content when select value changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a form when the user chooses "United States" or "Canada" from the country dropdown list, a state dropdown list will show up. Otherwise if the user chooses any other country, the state dropdown list will be replaced by a text input.

Here's an example (when the US is selected):

[image]

and when other country is selected:

[image]

I've pretty much got the result I want, but I was just wondering if there's better way to simply return the initial html content instead of writing the same thing all again with jQuery?

here's my jquery:

```
$('#country').change(function () {
    setRegion();
});
function setRegion() {
    var country = $('#country').val();
    var us_states = '<select id="us_states">...</select>';
    var ca_states = '<select id="ca_states">...</select>';
    if (country === 'United States') {
        $('#region_wrapper').html('<label for="us_states">State</label>' + us_states);
    } else if (country === 'Canada') {
        $('#region_wrapper').html('<label for="ca_states">State</label>' + ca_states);
    } else {
        $('#region_wrapper').html('<label for="region">Region, state, province, etc. (optional)</label>' + '<input type="text" id="region" placeholder="Region, state, province, etc. (optional)" />');
    }
}
```

and my html:

```
<li id="country_wrapper">
    <label for="country">Country</label>
    <select id="country">...</select>
</li>
<li id="region_wrapper">
    <label for="region">Region, state, province, etc. (optional)</label>
    <input type="text" id="region" placeholder="Region, state, province, etc. (optional)" />
</li>
```

In case my question isn't clear enough: I've pretty much got the result I want but I just want to know if there's an easier way to simply return "#region_wrapper" back to its initial html content when any other country is selected.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: By easier, do you mean fewer lines of code?
If so, then this is basically it if you are using Jquery,( with frameworks, you will be able to do that , though). 
The closest alternative is to use a switch, which will still result in as many lines of code. If you want i could put up an answer using switch.

Comment: @Adibas03 Yes because I always prefer simpler codes. It would be great if you can show me your ideas. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have a script to load the `region-wrapper` for other states, the same need not be done with HTML. Instead the function could just be called on loading the page as well as on change, to update the elements dynamically. Here is a simpler version of your code,

```html
<html>
<li id="country_wrapper">
    <label for="country">Country</label>
    <select id="country">
 <option>Others</option>
 <option>United States</option>
 <option>Canada</option>
    </select>
</li>
<li id="region_wrapper">
</li>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
setRegion();
$('#country').change(function () {
    setRegion();
});
function setRegion() {
    var country = $('#country').val();
    var us_states = '<select id="us_states"><option>US1</option><option>US2</option></select>';
    var ca_states = '<select id="ca_states"><option>CA1</option><option>CA2</option></select>';
    if (country === 'United States') {
        $('#region_wrapper').html('<label for="us_states">State</label>' + us_states);
    } else if (country === 'Canada') {
        $('#region_wrapper').html('<label for="ca_states">State</label>' + ca_states);
    } else {
        $('#region_wrapper').html('<label for="region">Region, state, province, etc. (optional)</label>' + '<input type="text" id="region" placeholder="Region, state, province, etc. (optional)" />');
    }
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: I thought of this too but then I was wondering if there's anything I could do with jQuery to make it append the initial html between <li id="region_wrapper"></li> Still thanks a lot for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to create `<li>` for US, Canada and Others and then show hide them based on the dropdown value instead on every time cretaing the HTMl in jquery and appending them inside other element. Check this link [Better Performance, Empty Elements Or Create And Destroy With Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361373/better-performance-empty-elements-or-create-and-destroy-with-javascript)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#region_wrapper_others').hide();
  $('#region_wrapper_canada').hide();
  $('#country').change(function () {
    setRegion();
});
function setRegion() {
    var country = $('#country').val();
    if (country === 'United States') {
        $('#region_wrapper_us').show();
        $('#region_wrapper_canada').hide();
        $('#region_wrapper_others').hide();
    } else if (country === 'Canada') {
        $('#region_wrapper_us').hide();
        $('#region_wrapper_canada').show();
        $('#region_wrapper_others').hide();
    } else {
        $('#region_wrapper_us').hide();
        $('#region_wrapper_canada').hide();
        $('#region_wrapper_others').show();
    }
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="country_wrapper">
    <label for="country">Country</label>
    <select id="country">
      <option>United States</option>
      <option>Canada</option>
      <option>Country1</option>
      <option>Country2</option>
      <option>Country3</option>
    </select>
</li>
<li id="region_wrapper_others">
    <label for="region">Region, state, province, etc. (optional)</label>
    <input type="text" id="region" placeholder="Region, state, province, etc. (optional)" />
</li>
<li id="region_wrapper_us">
    <label for="us_states">State</label>
    <select id="us_states">
        <option>US State 1</option>
        <option>US State 2</option>
    </select>
</li>
<li id="region_wrapper_canada">
    <label for="ca_states">State</label>
    <select id="ca_statesca_states">
        <option>Canada State 1</option>
        <option>Canada State 2</option>
    </select>
</li>
```

Comment: This was what I tried first but then I thought maybe I could simply replace a few codes by using jQuery. But still, thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Although it ends up in as many lines of code or more, a basic `switch` implementation would be

```
$('#country').change(function () {
    setRegion();
});

function setRegion() {
    var country = $('#country').val();
    var us_states = '<select id="us_states">...</select>';
    var ca_states = '<select id="ca_states">...</select>';

    switch(country) {
        case 'United States':
            $('#region_wrapper').html('<label for="us_states">State</label>' + us_states);
            break;
        case 'Canada':
            $('#region_wrapper').html('<label for="ca_states">State</label>' + ca_states);
            break;
        default:
            $('#region_wrapper').html('<label for="region">Region, state, province, etc. (optional)</label>' + '<input type="text" id="region" placeholder="Region, state, province, etc. (optional)" />');
            break;
    }
}
```

And the HTML code, remains unchanged

```
<li id="country_wrapper">
    <label for="country">Country</label>
    <select id="country">...</select>
</li>
<li id="region_wrapper">
    <label for="region">Region, state, province, etc. (optional)</label>
    <input type="text" id="region" placeholder="Region, state, province, etc. (optional)" />
</li>
```

Not necessarily simpler, but maybe neater.
Hope this helps.